In Google's Directory API, how can I get details for more than one user in a request?
I want to get the details for the members of a group in the Google Directory API.
I see that I can list the members of the group with GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{group_id}/members, but what is returned isn't the full admin#directory#user or admin#directory#group details, but rather a list of admin#directory#member, which gives me barely more than the type and id of each. With this, I could make individual queries to get the details of each member, but that starts adding up to a lot of HTTP calls.
Is there a way to do this that involves fewer than (num pages of members + num members) queries?

Is there a way to get details instead of member representations for the members of a group?
If not, is there an endpoint where I can query for more than one user at a time, by
ID or by email?

